# Are there any words similar to "abnormal"?

Tags: prefixes

If we remove *ab-,* the word *abnormal* becomes *normal,* which is the opposite. Are there any other words that are similar and start with the prefix *ab-*?

Comment: Hi Asghar, any standard dictionary will list words alphabetically, you will find all the ab- words there.

Comment: @Mynamite and there will be a lot of them, and most of them not examples of what is sought.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it asks for a list.

Comment: On-topic because it asks if this happens or not (a list would answer, but not be required to answer).

Answer (score 4):

Because *abnormal* doesn't in origin mean "not normal" but "away from normal" or "off the normal" to find other words where *ab-* + [word] means "not [word]" we need to find things where logically being away from it means being not it:

*Abaxial* (in the obsolete sense opposing *axial* rather than the sense opposing *adaxial*).

*Abhominal* (obsolete, obscure, and likely based on a back-formation based on a false etymology of *abominable*, but it does mean "inhuman" while *hominal* means "human").

*Abhuman*? It does entail not being human, though also having at least some human features too, so I probably would say this doesn't count, but it's worth mentioning.

*Abjunct* (obsolete and rare—only one attested use—and *junct* is obsolete too, but this is a nice clean opposition).

*Abirritant* (rare, but still in modern-day use; an abirritant reduces irritation while an *irritant* causes it).

You'll find much more where *abX* is a particular form of *X* (e.g. *abuse* is a bad form of *use*), where *abX* is opposed by *adX*, or where *abX* is a synonym or close synonym of *X*.

Comment: **Abnegation** does not fit in well here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abnegation

Comment: @WayfaringStranger so *abnegation* is not *ab-* negation :)

Answer (score 0):

The type ab-normal seems indeed to be rare. I looked through Hans Marchand, Word formation ( full title see below).
But the Latin prefix ab  (corresponds in this case to English off) is rare as a prefix meaning the contrary or not being, the most usual being the Greek prefix a- privativum or the variant an + vowel. Such formations are usual in science as a-septic. Outside the branches of science there are

amoral apolitical asymmetric atemporal (timeless) atonal.

There are other prefixes expressing negativity beside a-:

dis ex in (variants il+l, ir+r) non un

Source: Hans Marchand, The Categories and Types of Present-Day English Word-Formation, Beck Verlag München, 1969-2, 545 pages.

http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2723248&fileId=S0022226700002863

[http://www.amazon.com/categories-present-day-word-formation-synchronic-diachronic-approach/dp/B0029OGXQA/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1421605157&sr=8-5&keywords=Hans+marchand%2C+English+word-formation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029OGXQA)

Comment: So you're saying that "abnormal" is abnormal?

Comment: The prefix ab + adjective didn't become productive. It is not illogical as it means "off from normal". Why it didn't become productive is another question. It seems in-, un-, non- were already in common use. "abnormal" might be a singular creation based on Latin "ab normis" meaning deviating from the normal rules.